# Asp.net - how to make a page for every individual user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Basically I want a page in which can be seen user details. Like the twitter or facebook profile pages.

Comment: What problem are you having retrieving the data for the currently logged-in user?

Comment: No. I want to make a view that shows data for registered user. Like when I click on a profile picture it takes me to the persons profile page.

Comment: You need to pass some sort of identifier to the server side (typically via URL route or query string) indicating which user you want to load data for. The server side needs to read that value and obtain the appropriate content for that user and return it to the client. That's how most websites work these days, so it sounds like you need to just follow a basic tutorial that involves putting together a website that accesses a database.

Answer (score 1):

Design an html page. For example, the Profile.cshtml file. Send the user information logged into this page and write this data in the places you want to set.

```
 public ActionResult Profile()
 {
      ViewBag.User = User;
      return View();
 }
```

implemented in this way between html

```
<div>@ViewBag.User.Name</div>
```